# If- statement not working in scrapy

Tags: python, if-statement, scrapy, web-crawler

I've built a crawler using scrapy to crawl into a sitemap and scrape required components from all the links in the sitemap.

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
 name = "functie"
 allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
 sitemap_urls = ["http://www.xyz.nl/sitemap.xml"] 

 def parse(self, response): 
  item = MyItem()
  sel = Selector(response)

  item['url'] = response.url
  item['h1'] = sel.xpath("//h1[@class='no-bd']/text()").extract()
  item['jobtype'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name=".Keyword"]/@value').extract()
  item['count'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name="Count"]/@value').extract()
  item['location'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name="Location"]/@value').extract()
  yield item
```

The **item['location']** can have null values at some cases. In that particular case i want to scrape other component and store it in **item['location']**.
The code i've tried is:

```
item['location'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name="Location"]/@value').extract()
if not item['location']:
 item['location'] = sel.xpath('//a[@class="location"]/text()').extract()
```

But it doesn't checks the **if-condition** and returns empty if value is empty in the input field for location. Any help would be highly useful.

Comment: Are you sure the condition is not called, or does maybe the second `sel.xpath` also return a 'null' value? Did you check by putting e.g. a print statement in there? Also, what exactly would that "null value" be?

Comment: `.extract()` returns a list. a list with a single empty string is evaluated as `True`

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to check the length of `item['location']` instead.

```
item['location'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name="Location"]/@value').extract()
if len(item['location']) < 1:
    item['location'] = sel.xpath(//a[@class="location"]/text()').extract()')
```

Regardless, have you considered combining the two xpaths with a `|`?

```
item['location'] = sel.xpath('//input[@name="Location"]/@value | //a[@class="location"]/text()').extract()'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
if(item[location]==""):
     item['location'] = sel.xpath('//a[@class="location"]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is best solved with a custom [item pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html). 
 
**1)** Open `pipelines.py` and check your desired if condition within a Pipeline class:

```
class LocPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # check if key "location" is in item dict
        if not item.get("location"):
            # if not, try specific xpath
            item['location'] = sel.xpath('//a[@class="location"]/text()').extract()
        else:
            # if location was already found, do nothing
            pass

        return item
```

**2)** The next step is to add the custom `LocPipeline()` to your `settings.py` file:

 
`ITEM_PIPELINES = {'myproject.pipelines.LocPipeline': 300}`

Adding the custom pipeline to your settings, scrapy will automatically call the `LocPipeline().process_item()` after `MySpider().parse()` and search for the alternative XPath if no location is found yet.